# How to set option button in excel as rating

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

How can I set option button in excel so when I choose the third button,it will give me 3, if I press on fourth button it will give me number 4, like this:

[image]

Comment: I think this can be done using VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "form controls" option button you can set its "Cell link" (right click - format control - control), it does exactly what you need.

[image]